# Failed to load Jitsi Meet API - Error in lib-jitsi-meet during initJitsiConference (TypeError: Cannot read property ‘substr’)

Tags: javascript, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm trying to use the Jitsi Meet API to create Jitsi Meet video conferences with custom GUI.

I’m receiving a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null` when calling `initJitsiConference()`.

**Characteristics of the system environment:**

- The default Jitsi Meet installation has not been changed;
- I didn't
  install / configure the Prosody JWT token authentication plugin;
- I am
  running the test.html application on one domain, example:
  https://mydomain1.com and Jitsi Meet on other domain, for example:
  https://meet.myotherdomain2.com

**I get the following error message (console Chrome):**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null - JitsiConference.js:276
    at se.resourceCreator (JitsiConference.js:276)
    at A.createRoom (xmpp.js:475)
    at se._init (JitsiConference.js:310)
    at new se (JitsiConference.js:130)
    at c.initJitsiConference (JitsiConnection.js:113)
```

**Looking at JitsiConference.js on line 276 i see this:**

```
JitsiConference.resourceCreator = function(jid, isAuthenticatedUser) {
    let mucNickname;

    if (isAuthenticatedUser) {
        // For authenticated users generate a random ID.
        mucNickname = RandomUtil.randomHexString(8).toLowerCase();
    } else {
        // We try to use the first part of the node (which for anonymous users
        // on prosody is a UUID) to match the previous behavior (and maybe make
        // debugging easier).
        mucNickname = Strophe.getNodeFromJid(jid).substr(0, 8) //// 276 LINE ////
            .toLowerCase();

        // But if this doesn't have the required format we just generate a new
        // random nickname.
        const re = /[0-9a-f]{8}/g;

        if (!re.test(mucNickname)) {
            mucNickname = RandomUtil.randomHexString(8).toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    return mucNickname;
};
```

**My API javascript (mydomain.com/test.html) looks like this:**

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://meet.jit.si/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
JitsiMeetJS.init();

const options = {
    serviceUrl:'https://meet.jit.si/http-bind',
    hosts: {
        domain: 'meet.jit.si',
        muc: 'conference.meet.jit.si',
    },
    bosh: 'https://meet.jit.si/http-bind',
    useStunTurn: true
}

var connection = new JitsiMeetJS.JitsiConnection(null, null, options);

const confOptions = {
    openBridgeChannel: true
}

room = connection.initJitsiConference("testconference1", confOptions);
</script>
```

I tried with other public instances:

- meet.jit.si
- jitsi2.linux.it
- jitsi-1.belnet.be
- jitsi.riot.im
- de-bra-1.jitsi.rocks
- meet.xrv.pt

**And got similar errors (console Chrome):**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null - JitsiConference.js:263 
    at oe.resourceCreator (JitsiConference.js:263)
    at t.value (xmpp.js:461)
    at oe._init (JitsiConference.js:297)
    at new oe (JitsiConference.js:127)
    at c.initJitsiConference (JitsiConnection.js:113)
```

**Log file (Jicofo.log) I found [WARNING] and [SEVERE]**

```
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:23.771 WARNING: [22] org.jitsi.jicofo.FocusManager.log() No dedicated JVB MUC XMPP connection configured - falling back to the default XMPP connection
...
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:24.335 SEVERE: [28] org.jitsi.impl.protocol.xmpp.OpSetSimpleCapsImpl.getFeatures().144 Failed to discover features for speakerstats.meet.myserver.com: XMPP error reply received from speakerstats.meet.myserver.com: XMPPError: service-unavailable - cancel
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:24.337 SEVERE: [28] org.jitsi.impl.protocol.xmpp.OpSetSimpleCapsImpl.getFeatures().144 Failed to discover features for focus.meet.myserver.com: XMPP error reply received from focus.meet.myserver.com: XMPPError: service-unavailable - wait
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:24.345 SEVERE: [28] org.jitsi.impl.protocol.xmpp.OpSetSimpleCapsImpl.getFeatures().144 Failed to discover features for conferenceduration.meet.myserver.com: XMPP error reply received from conferenceduration.meet.myserver.com: XMPPError: service-unavailable - cancel
...
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:29.629 WARNING: [40] org.jitsi.jicofo.bridge.BridgeSelector.log() No pub-sub node mapped for jvbbrewery@internal.auth.meet.myserver.com/2671872e-fccb-49e9-866b-28813c831825
...
Jicofo 2020-05-15 20:05:29.651 INFO: [55] org.jitsi.jicofo.bridge.JvbDoctor.log() Scheduled health-check task for: jvbbrewery@internal.auth.meet.myserver.com/2671872e-fccb-49e9-866b-28813c831825
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler (file:/usr/share/jicofo/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$LocatorProxy.getEncoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

**Log file (jvb.log) I found [WARNING]**

```
2020-05-15 20:05:24.645 WARNING: [22] Videobridge.start#906: No authorized source regexp configured. Will accept requests from any source.
```

What mistake should I be making?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Excuse me, my English language is weak.*

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing more carefully, I concluded that I was not waiting (`addEventListener`) for the CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED event and with some modifications to the code...

I also removed the option `bosh: 'https://meet.jit.si/http-bind'`, as it looks obsolete.

I included the dependencies of the javascritps:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/strophe.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/strophejs-plugin-disco/lib/strophe.disco.js?v=1"></script>
```

**Code with the modifications:**

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/strophe.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/strophejs-plugin-disco/lib/strophe.disco.js?v=1"></script>
<script src="https://meet.jit.si/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js"></script>
<script>

function onConnectionSuccess(){
    const confOptions = {
        openBridgeChannel: true
    }
    room = connection.initJitsiConference("abcdef", confOptions);
    room.join();
    room.myUserId();
    console.log('CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED');
}

JitsiMeetJS.init();

JitsiMeetJS.setLogLevel(JitsiMeetJS.logLevels.ERROR);

const options = {
    serviceUrl:'https://meet.jit.si/http-bind',
    hosts: {
        domain: 'meet.jit.si',
        muc: 'conference.meet.jit.si'
    }
}

var connection = new JitsiMeetJS.JitsiConnection(null, null, options);

connection.addEventListener(JitsiMeetJS.events.connection.CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED, onConnectionSuccess);

connection.connect();

</script>
```

See that in the [API documentation in item 4 of "Getting started"](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/API.md#getting-started), the explanation is to wait for the CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED event and only then create the JitsiConference object.
Now it looks like everything is working properly.

Thank you all for your time and dedication.

*P.S .: I am new to StackOverflow and I am trying my best to give the best answer that can help the community.*